# How to Generating Pdf using jsPDF in LWC but PDF not generated?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning

I am trying to generate pdf using JSPdf in LWC using the below code. It is happening just before the line in JS

```
doc.table(30, 30, JSON.stringify(this.oppListDate), this.headers, { 
 autosize:true });
```

please advise how to fix.

html:

```
   <template>
   <lightning-button label="Export PDF" variant="brand" onclick={saveAsPdf} icon- 
   name="utility:download"
        title="Export PDF"></lightning-button>
  </template>
```

JS:-

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import searchOpp from '@salesforce/apex/LwcDateCmpCtrl.searchOpp';
import jsPDF from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jsPDF';
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";

export default class LwcSearchDate extends LightningElement {

   oppListDate = []

headers = this.createHeaders([
   "Id",
   "Name",
   "StageName",
   "Probability",
   "Account.Name"
 ]);

 renderedCallback() {

    if (this.jsPdfInitialized) {
      return;
   }
    this.jsPdfInitialized = true;

    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, jsPDF)
    ]);
 }

 saveAsPdf(){

  console.log('saveAsPdf ##' );

  const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;

  const doc = new jsPDF({
      encryption: {
          userPassword: "user",
          ownerPassword: "owner",
          userPermissions: ["print", "modify", "copy", "annot-forms"]
          // try changing the user permissions granted
      } 
  });


     doc.text("This is test pdf", 20, 20);
     doc.table(30, 30, JSON.stringify(this.oppListDate), this.headers, { autosize:true 
      });
     doc.save("demo.pdf");

   }

 createHeaders(keys) {
   var result = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i += 1) {
       result.push({
          id: keys[i],
          name: keys[i],
          prompt: keys[i],
          width: 65,
          align: "center",
          padding: 0
      });
  }
   return result;
  }

 }
```

Class:-

```
    @AuraEnabled
  public static List<Opportunity> searchOpp(Date dateStr1, Date dateStr2, Account 
 objAcc, Decimal prob, String stageName){
 try {

 List<Account> accName = [select id from Account where Name =: objAcc.Name WITH 
SECURITY_ENFORCED];

   if(String.isNotBlank(stageName)){

     List<Opportunity> oppList = [select Id, Name, StageName, AccountId, 
    Probability, Account.Name, CreatedDate from Opportunity where CreatedDate >: 
   dateStr1 and CreatedDate <: dateStr2 and AccountId =: accName and Probability =: prob 
  and StageName =: stageName WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
  system.debug('oppList ' + oppList);
  return oppList;
  }else{
   return null ;
    }
 } catch (Exception e) {
  throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
 }
 }
```

Comment: Do you see any logs in the console ?
Can you create a basic pdf as 
`const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm', 'a4');`
`doc.setFontSize(15);`
`doc.text("This is test pdf", 20, 20);`
`doc.save("demo.pdf");`

Comment: @N_H1922 No I have not seen any log in console.

Comment: @N_H1922 Yes Basic PDF is create but when I Passed below Line it will not worked. 

doc.table(30, 30, JSON.stringify(this.oppListData), this.headers, { autosize: true });